# php mysqli query function

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have recently changed from MySQL to MySQLI and i am struggling to convert all my mysql class to mysqli. I am trying to make this function work

```
public function DoQuery($query)
{
    mysqli::$link->query($query);
}
```

Also the $link is in a function

```
public static function Connect()
{
    $link = new mysqli(mysql::$hostname, mysql::$username, mysql::$password, mysql::$database);
    if ($link->connect_errno > 0)
    {
        mysqli::error("could not close mysql connection");
    }
    mysqli::$connected = true;
}
```

And at the top off the class i have declared

```
public static $link;
```

Comment: `self::$link` on your `Connect` function, otherwise you're creating a local var instead of using the static var.

Comment: Wait, what @YourCommonSense? SO members are constantly telling people to not use `MySQL` and convert, but you're concerned why he's doing it? Am I missing something?

Comment: @BeatAlex SO members usually have no clue, you know. And yes, I am concened also in where did my comment go.

Comment: @user3665091 why do you want to change from MySQL to MySQLI?

Comment: I am genuinely interested in why you think he shouldn't! After the majority (not saying that they were correct) voting to change it, it just seems odd you think it's not necessary. @YourCommonSense I'm just confused, as `mysql_*` is deprecated now I thought anyway?

Comment: @BeatAlex Nowhere did I say he shouldn't. I merely asked why he is doing so. Yes, mysql functions are marked as deprecated in a recent version. It is not that big deal, actually.

Comment: Also, @user3665091 why do you want to call your class mysqli, instead of keeping old name?

Comment: I have one class called mysql and one class called mysqli. I am allowing a config value to select what driver to use so if i did want to still use mysql i could? And the main reason i want to change is because so many people have told me its better. And lets be fair hardly anyone uses mysql on theyre project since it got deprecated.

Comment: it doesn't seem like a driver. For the backward compatibility you should keep your old mysql class, while mysqli indeed have to be implemented as a driver in it. But having separate mysqli class makes no sense - would you run through all your codes adding i to all the calls?

Comment: either way, your main problem is a class name. PHP already has mysqli class, and there is conflict surely